# I want to get last message UID from IMAP INBOX

Tags: imap, telnet, inbox

How to find the last email ( message UID ) using IMAP commands.

I am using putty on windows pc to connect to imap server .

Answer (score 2):

When you select the inbox, it will tell you how many messages are in the message via the `EXISTS` response.   This number is also the highest message sequence numbers run the mailbox. You can then get the highest UID in the mailbox by fetching the UID for this message.

That is:

```
 a SELECT INBOX
 ...
 * 23 EXISTS
 ....
 b FETCH 23 (UID)
 * 23 FETCH (UID 207)
 b OK
```

Therfore, 207 is the highest UID in the mailbox.

You could also do UID SEARCH ALL and take the largest number returned.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to ask for the `UID` of message identified by `*` which [represents the largest number in use](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-90):

```
>>> a SELECT INBOX
...
<<< * 3 EXISTS
<<< a OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed.

>>> b FETCH * (UID)
<<< * 3 FETCH (UID 283)
<<< b OK Fetch completed.
```

That said, I'm curious on why you want to know the highest UID in the mailbox. That value is often meaningless; you do not need it for any IMAP command and it does *not* represent any upper bound on the UID which was ever in that mailbox -- you want to track the `UIDNEXT` for that.